# How to skip the comment lines in pandas but retain the commented lines in the op file

Tags: python, pandas

```
Data=pd.read("abc.csv",comment="#", index_col=False, low_memory=False)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to retain and where? Do you want to rewrite the CSV file but keep comments? If so, how are you changing the data in the dataframe? Please include a short, simple test CSV and what output you want.

Comment: The file which has #comments in the first two line of the csv file and which I should read it from the 3rd line and it ie comments should be retained in the op file.

Comment: You could use `pandas.read_csv` and set its `skiprows` parameter to 2. Now it will skip the first two lines. Later, if you want to save data to a different file, reopen the first file and use the file object's `readline` method to read the first two lines. Write those to to output file before the data.

Comment: Post a [mcve] and include software version numbers. End of Review.